# How does a websocket cdn work with bidirectional data?

Tags: websocket, cdn, cloudflare

I see that cloudflare has a websocket cdn, but I'm confused with how it would cache bidirectional data.  With a normal http request, it would cache the response and then serve it from the CDN.

With a web socket, how does cloudflare cache the data?  Especially since the socket can be bi-dirctional.

Comment: Please provide a reference for a websocket CDN because that seems to make no conceptual sense.  There are no structured requests with a webSocket like there is with HTTP.  So, you're just sending data on a webSocket and it's up to the receiving server to know what to do with that data.  It make generate a response or it may not.  Thus, a CDN doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: it didn't make complete sense to me either, thus the question - here's the link https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supports-websockets/

Answer (score 4):

Caching is really only a small part of what a CDN does.

CloudFlare (and really any CDN that would offer this service), would serve two purposes off the top of my hand:

1. Network connection optimization - The browser endpoint would be able to have a keepalive connection to whatever the closest Point of Presence (PoP) is to them. Depending on CloudFlare's internal architecture, it could then take an optimized network path to a PoP closer to the origin, or to the origin itself. This network path may have significantly better routing and performance than having the browser go straight to the origin.
2. Site consistency - By offering WebSockets, a CDN is able to let end users stay on the same URL without having to mess around with any cross-origin issues or complexities of maintaining multiple domains.

Both of these go hand in hand with a term often called "Full Site Acceleration" or "Dynamic Site Acceleration".